# Section headers in margins

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, resume

I'm working on my resume in LyX and I would like my section headers to look like [this](http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res2.pdf). What should I write in the preamble to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use the titlesec package to modify the definition of the \section command. in lyx you can add latex-code manually by going to the document preferences: Document->Settings -> Latex preamble. I marked the part of code you have to put in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%to lyn preamble from here

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont
\sffamily\bfseries\filleft}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

%to here

\begin{document}

\section{Objective}
\noindent
Auditing/Analysis of Operations

\section{Education}
\noindent
B.S. in Management, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY, May 1986
Concentrations in Accounting and Management Systems
QPA 3.9 in major, 3.7 overall

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works pretty well - except the header is still above the text, thus taking up space. Any way to make it aligned with the text?

Comment: @AmirRachum: The answer below with the link to the document source does this properly.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [source](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222200455/http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res2.tex) of the document you linked to.  Just copy it and and change it.

You need the [`res`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200222200445/http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) class which is downloadable from the same place.

Comment: This solution is better because the section header is vertically flush with the text (responding to the OP's question to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the [europecv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/europecv.html) package?

I've been using that to write my own CV.

From CTAN:

> The europecv class is an unofficial
>   LaTeX implementation of the standard
>   model for curricula vitae (the
>   “Europass CV”) as recommended by the
>   European Commission. Although
>   primarily intended for users in the
>   European Union, the class is flexible
>   enough to be used for any kind of
>   curriculum vitae.
>
> The class has localisations for all
>   the official languages of the EU (plus
>   Catalan), as well as options
>   permitting input in UTF-8 and koi8-r.
>
> See also [curve](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/curve.html)
>   [currvita](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/currvita.html)
>   [esieecv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/esieecv.html) [vita](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/vita.html)
>
> The author is Nicola Vitacolonna.

Answer (score 3):

Er, perhaps I'm a little slow these days (go easy, guys, I'm being rhetorical), but as far as I can tell from your example, what you've got there is a table. A `longtable` if you want to run things over one page.

(Or am I just being painfully dense?)