# Margins as Subsections

Tags: margins, sectioning, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

Is there a way to have subsection titles show in the margin of the page?

I'm never happy with subsections, I usually tend to avoid them. What I do like, is letting the readers know what's going on by using \marginpar.
It would sometimes be useful if some of these (more important) margin notes were actual subsections of the document.

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/section-headers-in-margins)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [titlesec](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/titlesec.html) package. The manual (page 24-25) shows an example of a heading in the margin.