# Vertical alignment in sections beginning with itemize

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, itemize, enumitem, cv

I'm working on a résumé which [places section headers in a widened left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/10906).  In the example below, I am trying to get the `itemize` in section *Bar* to be vertically aligned with the section title, much like the content is aligned in the other two sections.  However, there is an undesirable gap before an `itemize` which begins a section, despite several settings which aim to prevent this (e.g., `topsep=0pt`).

[image: Observed/Desired image]

**What am I missing to "consume" this space and bring the `itemize` up?**  I've tried negative `\vspace` and `\vskip`, but that's a hack at best, and is prone to much trial-and-error.  (Relatedly, are some of my `\setlist` options unnecessary for this?)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, left=1.5in]{geometry}

% Section headers in margins
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/10906
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\sffamily}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep, nosep, topsep=0pt}    
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5ex}


\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\textbf{Metasyntactic University \dotfill Date}
\begin{itemize}
\item Degree 1
\item Certificate 2
\end{itemize}

\section{Foo}
This is some brief free-form text about some stuff that I can do.  Did you know I do Thing~3 and Thing~4?  It's pretty cool; I know.

\section{Bar}
\begin{itemize}
\item Skill 5
\item Skill 6
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct this behaviour manually by vertically skipping back to the same baseline:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, left=1.5in]{geometry}

% Section headers in margins
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/10906
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\sffamily}
  {}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
  {4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nolistsep, nosep, topsep=0pt}    
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5ex}


\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\textbf{Metasyntactic University \dotfill Date}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Degree 1
  \item Certificate 2
\end{itemize}

\section{Foo}
This is some brief free-form text about some stuff that I can do.  Did you know I do Thing~3 and Thing~4?  It's pretty cool; I know.

\section{Bar}
\leavevmode% Start paragraph
\par% End paragraph/enter vertical mode
\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}% Vertically jump back to baseline of section
\begin{itemize}
  \item Skill 5
  \item Skill 6
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```