# Extending fullwidth into one margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules, cv, fullwidth

I'm working on a résumé which [places section headers in a widened left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/10906).  I'd like to use a `fullwidth` environment for the heading at the top of the page.  Formally speaking, this would extend *into* the left margin to line up with the section headers.  However, I can only get the heading to extend about two-thirds of the way to the right margin:

[image: Observed vs desired]

I added a `leftmargin=-1in` to the `fullwidth` package declaration to get the proper left-alignment, but even without it, the heading doesn't stretch the whole way to the right margin, as defined.  **Why is this, and how can I correct it?**

(I also get a warning on the `\hline` about a "misplaced `\noalign`", which may be related.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, left=1.5in]{geometry}

% Section headers in margins
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/10906
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
{\sffamily}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[leftmargin=-1in]{fullwidth}


\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
\textsf{\Huge{John Q Doe}} \hfill johndoe@example.com
\hline
\end{fullwidth}

\section{Foo}
This is some brief free-form text about some stuff that I can do.  Did you know I do Thing~3 and Thing~4?  It's pretty cool; I know.

\section{Bar and Baz}
\ldots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `adjustwidth` from [`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) instead. It allows you to adjust the margin widths for a specific piece of text (left and/or right; into/from the margins):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in, left=1.5in]{geometry}

% Section headers in margins
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1315/5764
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]
  {\sffamily}
  {}{0pt}{}
  \titlespacing{\section}
  {4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{2pc}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{0pt}
  \textsf{\Huge John Q Doe} \hfill johndoe@example.com \par
  \hrulefill
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{Foo}
This is some brief free-form text about some stuff that I can do.  Did you know I do Thing~3 and Thing~4?  It's pretty cool; I know.

\section{Bar and Baz}
\ldots

\end{document}
```

Also, `\hline` is limited to a `tabular`-like scope. Rather use something like `\hrulefill`.

Comment: Thanks! I especially like how the use of `\par` and `\hrulefill` give a horizontal rule that better splits the vertical space between the heading and the first section.