# Subsection title does not align with its section title under [left margin]

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, sectioning, titlesec

I put section title in `left margin` with use of `titlesec` package, and the first line of its text aligns with the title as expected. But its subsection title does not align. I tried with titlespacing but fail. What's wrong with my code? How to make the subsection title automatically align with its section title?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
  \titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filleft}{\Roman{section}.}{1em}{}
  \titlespacing{\section}{4em}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
  \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
  \section{First Section}This text aligns with its section header as expected.\par\vspace{3em}
  \section{Second Section}
  \subsection{How to top align this subsection title with its section title}
\end{document}
```

[image]