# titlesec margin style adds unnecessary space when using itemize

Tags: titlesec

When using [Section headers in margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/section-headers-in-margins) to put *paragraph* headings in the margin, when the paragraph starts with an `itemize` or `enumerate`, an extra space appears at the top of the paragraph, which is not the case if it starts with a normal text.

How do I prevent this?

Example code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont
\bfseries\filleft}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\paragraph{first paragraph with title}
\begin{itemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\item item three
\end{itemize}
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{second paragraph with title}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Which outputs:
[image: Output screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space you're seeing is just the (blank) first line of the paragraph, before the list begins. To remove it, you can use `enumitem` to add negative spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{startitemize}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{startenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[startitemize]{
    label=\textbullet,
    before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{-\topsep},
}
\setlist[startenumerate]{
    label=\arabic*.,
    before=\leavevmode\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{-\topsep},
}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[leftmargin]
{\normalfont
\bfseries\filleft}
{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}
{4pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\paragraph{first paragraph with title}
\begin{startitemize}
\item item one
\item item two
\item item three
\end{startitemize}
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{second paragraph with title}
\lipsum[1]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this happen automatically, so that if the paragraph begins with an itemize/enumerate, the so-called blank line gets deleted? After all, I have not entered any blank line between the heading and the itemize.

Comment: @noxewa I don't know if it's possible to have LaTeX detect everything automatically, but you can certainly make the process half automatic by defining new list environments with `enumitem` to remove the space. I updated my example with such environments.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite good enough!